# Creating a Dataframe Table from two list first with the headers and second with each value as row in Python

Tags: python, dataframe, sorting, web

I have two list that I got using Web Scraping, my first list is:

```
[' RPJ',' TipoEmpresa',' TipoSector', ' NombreEmpresa', ' RUC', ' CIIU',' Ejercicio','TipoInformacion',  ' Trimestre',  ' Moneda', ' MetodoFlujoEfectivo', ' Cuenta', ' DescripcionCuenta', ' Monto1',  ' Monto2', ' Monto3', ' Monto4']
```

And my second list is:

```
     '2|I00004|SOCIEDADES|ADMINISTRADORAS|DE|FONDOS|DE|INVERSION|||AC|CAPITALES|SOCIEDAD|ADMINISTRADORA|DE|FONDOS|DE|INVERSION|S.A.|20504893295|6599|2014|Anual|Individual|Anual|Soles|Método|Directo|2D0201|Costo|de|Ventas||-79|-90|0|0',
     '3|I00004|SOCIEDADES|ADMINISTRADORAS|DE|FONDOS|DE|INVERSION|||AC|CAPITALES|SOCIEDAD|ADMINISTRADORA|DE|FONDOS|DE|INVERSION|S.A.|20504893295|6599|2014|Anual|Individual|Anual|Soles|Método|Directo|2D02ST|Ganancia|(Pérdida)|Bruta|12353|34428|0|0',
     '4|I00004|SOCIEDADES|ADMINISTRADORAS|DE|FONDOS|DE|INVERSION|||AC|CAPITALES|SOCIEDAD|ADMINISTRADORA|DE|FONDOS|DE|INVERSION|S.A.|20504893295|6599|2014|Anual|Individual|Anual|Soles|Método|Directo|2D0302|Gastos|de|Ventas|y|Distribución|0|0|0|0',
     '5|I00004|SOCIEDADES|ADMINISTRADORAS|DE|FONDOS|DE|INVERSION|||AC|CAPITALES|SOCIEDAD|ADMINISTRADORA|DE|FONDOS|DE|INVERSION|S.A.|20504893295|6599|2014|Anual|Individual|Anual|Soles|Método|Directo|2D0301|Gastos|de|Administración|-6992|-12647|0|0',
     '6|I00004|SOCIEDADES|ADMINISTRADORAS|DE|FONDOS|DE|INVERSION|||AC|CAPITALES|SOCIEDAD|ADMINISTRADORA|DE|FONDOS|DE|INVERSION|S.A.|20504893295|6599|2014|Anual|Individual|Anual|Soles|Método|Directo|2D0407|Ganancia|(Pérdida)|de|la|baja|en|Activos|Financieros|medidos|al|Costo|Amortizado|0|0|0|0',
     '7|I00004|SOCIEDADES|ADMINISTRADORAS|DE|FONDOS|DE|INVERSION|||AC|CAPITALES|SOCIEDAD|ADMINISTRADORA|DE|FONDOS|DE|INVERSION|S.A.|20504893295|6599|2014|Anual|Individual|Anual|Soles|Método|Directo|2D0403|Otros|Ingresos|Operativos|36|61|0|0',
     '8|I00004|SOCIEDADES|ADMINISTRADORAS|DE|FONDOS|DE|INVERSION|||AC|CAPITALES|SOCIEDAD|ADMINISTRADORA|DE|FONDOS|DE|INVERSION|S.A.|20504893295|6599|2014|Anual|Individual|Anual|Soles|Método|Directo|2D0404|Otros|Gastos|Operativos|-46|-54|0|0',
     '9|I00004|SOCIEDADES|ADMINISTRADORAS|DE|FONDOS|DE|INVERSION|||AC|CAPITALES|SOCIEDAD|ADMINISTRADORA|DE|FONDOS|DE|INVERSION|S.A.|20504893295|6599|2014|Anual|Individual|Anual|Soles|Método|Directo|2D0412|Otras|ganancias|(pérdidas)|0|0|0|0',
     '10|I00004|SOCIEDADES|ADMINISTRADORAS|DE|FONDOS|DE|INVERSION|||AC|CAPITALES|SOCIEDAD|ADMINISTRADORA|DE|FONDOS|DE|INVERSION|S.A.|20504893295|6599|2014|Anual|Individual|Anual|Soles|Método|Directo|2D03ST|Ganancia|(Pérdida)|por|actividades|de|operación|5351|21788|0|0']
```

As you see, each value from my second list is a row from the table that I want to make. I would like to have this result

[image]

I did this manually, but I have perhaps one hundred of thousand of 'rows' to add.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have two lists one with the column headers and one with the actual data, you can create a dictionary of values from the lists. Notice that I added 'ID' to headers as you need 'ID' as a column name in the dataframe. Then just create a dictionary by iterating over the rows after splitting them in scalar values and create a dict.

```
headers = ['ID',' RPJ',' TipoEmpresa',' TipoSector', ' NombreEmpresa', ' RUC', ' CIIU',' Ejercicio','TipoInformacion',  ' Trimestre',  ' Moneda', ' MetodoFlujoEfectivo', ' Cuenta', ' DescripcionCuenta', ' Monto1',  ' Monto2', ' Monto3', ' Monto4']
rows = ['1|I00004|SOCIEDADES|ADMINISTRADORAS|DE|FONDOS|DE|INVERSION|||AC|CAPITALES|SOCIEDAD|ADMINISTRADORA|DE|FONDOS|DE|INVERSION|S.A.|20504893295|6599|2014|Anual|Individual|Anual|Soles|Método|Directo|2D01ST|Ingresos|de|actividades|ordinarias|12432|34518|0|0',
 '2|I00004|SOCIEDADES|ADMINISTRADORAS|DE|FONDOS|DE|INVERSION|||AC|CAPITALES|SOCIEDAD|ADMINISTRADORA|DE|FONDOS|DE|INVERSION|S.A.|20504893295|6599|2014|Anual|Individual|Anual|Soles|Método|Directo|2D0201|Costo|de|Ventas||-79|-90|0|0',
 '3|I00004|SOCIEDADES|ADMINISTRADORAS|DE|FONDOS|DE|INVERSION|||AC|CAPITALES|SOCIEDAD|ADMINISTRADORA|DE|FONDOS|DE|INVERSION|S.A.|20504893295|6599|2014|Anual|Individual|Anual|Soles|Método|Directo|2D02ST|Ganancia|(Pérdida)|Bruta|12353|34428|0|0',
 '4|I00004|SOCIEDADES|ADMINISTRADORAS|DE|FONDOS|DE|INVERSION|||AC|CAPITALES|SOCIEDAD|ADMINISTRADORA|DE|FONDOS|DE|INVERSION|S.A.|20504893295|6599|2014|Anual|Individual|Anual|Soles|Método|Directo|2D0302|Gastos|de|Ventas|y|Distribución|0|0|0|0',
 '5|I00004|SOCIEDADES|ADMINISTRADORAS|DE|FONDOS|DE|INVERSION|||AC|CAPITALES|SOCIEDAD|ADMINISTRADORA|DE|FONDOS|DE|INVERSION|S.A.|20504893295|6599|2014|Anual|Individual|Anual|Soles|Método|Directo|2D0301|Gastos|de|Administración|-6992|-12647|0|0',
 '6|I00004|SOCIEDADES|ADMINISTRADORAS|DE|FONDOS|DE|INVERSION|||AC|CAPITALES|SOCIEDAD|ADMINISTRADORA|DE|FONDOS|DE|INVERSION|S.A.|20504893295|6599|2014|Anual|Individual|Anual|Soles|Método|Directo|2D0407|Ganancia|(Pérdida)|de|la|baja|en|Activos|Financieros|medidos|al|Costo|Amortizado|0|0|0|0',
 '7|I00004|SOCIEDADES|ADMINISTRADORAS|DE|FONDOS|DE|INVERSION|||AC|CAPITALES|SOCIEDAD|ADMINISTRADORA|DE|FONDOS|DE|INVERSION|S.A.|20504893295|6599|2014|Anual|Individual|Anual|Soles|Método|Directo|2D0403|Otros|Ingresos|Operativos|36|61|0|0',
 '8|I00004|SOCIEDADES|ADMINISTRADORAS|DE|FONDOS|DE|INVERSION|||AC|CAPITALES|SOCIEDAD|ADMINISTRADORA|DE|FONDOS|DE|INVERSION|S.A.|20504893295|6599|2014|Anual|Individual|Anual|Soles|Método|Directo|2D0404|Otros|Gastos|Operativos|-46|-54|0|0',
 '9|I00004|SOCIEDADES|ADMINISTRADORAS|DE|FONDOS|DE|INVERSION|||AC|CAPITALES|SOCIEDAD|ADMINISTRADORA|DE|FONDOS|DE|INVERSION|S.A.|20504893295|6599|2014|Anual|Individual|Anual|Soles|Método|Directo|2D0412|Otras|ganancias|(pérdidas)|0|0|0|0',
 '10|I00004|SOCIEDADES|ADMINISTRADORAS|DE|FONDOS|DE|INVERSION|||AC|CAPITALES|SOCIEDAD|ADMINISTRADORA|DE|FONDOS|DE|INVERSION|S.A.|20504893295|6599|2014|Anual|Individual|Anual|Soles|Método|Directo|2D03ST|Ganancia|(Pérdida)|por|actividades|de|operación|5351|21788|0|0']

dct = []
for row in rows:
  temp = {}
  for header, v in zip(headers,row.split("|")):
    temp[header] = v
  dct.append(temp)

df = pd.DataFrame(dct, index=[x for x in range(len(dct))])
print(df.head())
```